# Nhibernate and a large list of ids in a WHERE in restriction

Tags: nhibernate

I am perfomring a QueryOver query, and have a restriction cluase that effectively does a WHERE IN cluase.

If I will have thousands of results coming back from that inner query, this will obviously be a slow query right?

```
public List<SomeEntity> GetByIds(List<Guid> listOfIds)
{
  return NHibernateHelper.Session.QueryOver<SomeEntity>()
  .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.id).IsIn(listOfIds)
  .List();
}
```

Is it possible to convert this into a INNER JOIN somehow?

Comment: Is the `listOfIds` from objects that have a relationship with `SomeEntity`, by foreign key and/or a navigation property? And, if so, can you select these related objects by anything else then `IsIn` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to a sub-query or inner join. Your restriction is on the number of parameters you can add to a query in sql server, which is about 2.2 k parameters. The way your current code works you should split the parameters in chunks from about 2k and add them to a result list.

Answer (score 1):

if listOfIds comes from the same database then only when there is a realtionship, otherwise you have to use sql.

if listOfIds is large and doesnt come from the same source then this might be faster

```
Session.CreateSqlQuery("CREATE TEMP TABLE temp (Id)").ExecuteUpdate();
foreach (var id in listofids)
{
    Session.CreateSqlQuery("INSERT INTO temp (?)").SetParam(id).ExecuteUpdate();
}
Session.CreateSqlQuery("CREATE INDEX for temp (Id)").ExecuteUpdate();

return NHibernateHelper.Session.QueryOver<SomeEntity>()
    .UnderlyingCriteria.Add(Expression.Sql("0 < (SELECT Count(*) FROM temp t WHERE t.id = Id)"))
    .List<SomeEntity>();
```